# How to Fix Inconsistent Page Behavior When Resizing the Browser Window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three pages on my website, but when I resize the browser window, the pages don't behave consistently. When I resize the leftmost page, **during resize only that page is visible on the screen**, **and that's exactly what I want.**

However, when I resize the middle or rightmost page, for a moment it shows the previous or next page and when I resize the rightmost page fastly (making small and wide) it is going to the midddle page.

The leftmost page works fine for me, and I want the other pages to behave the same way. How can I achieve that?

You can test the pages with making the browser smaller and wider with the mouse.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>

    * {
      margin: 0;
      scroll-behavior: smooth;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-family: 'avenir_nextdemi_bold';
    }

    .outer-wrapper {
      width: 100vh;
      height: 100vw;
      transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100vh);
      transform-origin: top left;
      position: absolute;
      scrollbar-width: none;
      -ms-overflow-style: none;
      /*makes scroll disable on the whole page*/
      /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
      overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
      display: none;
    }

    .wrapper {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: row;
      /*if you want to add more pages turn the width to 400,500 etc..*/
      width: 300vw;
      transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100vh);
      transform-origin: top left;
    }

    /*Main settings*/
    .slide {
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    .one {
      background: orange;
  border: solid 0.5em green;

    }

    .two {
      background: blue;
  border: solid 0.5em red;

    }

    .three {
      background: yellow;
  border: solid 0.5em yellow;

    }

    .active {
      border-color: black;
    }
    
    p{
    font-size:4rem;
    color:white;
    margin-top:5em;
    text-align:center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="outer-wrapper">
    <div class="wrapper">

      <!--
      =============== 
      Left page
      ===============
      -->
      <div id="pageleft" class="slide one active">
                <p>
        left page
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--
      =============== 
      End left page
      ===============
      -->

      <!--
      =============== 
      Middle page
      ===============
      -->
      <div id="middle" class="slide two">
        <p>
        middle page
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--
      =============== 
      End middle page
      ===============
      -->

      <!--
      =============== 
      Right page
      ===============
      -->
      <div id="pageright" class="slide three ">
                <p>
        right page
        </p>
      </div>
      <!--
      =============== 
      End right page
      ===============
      -->
    </div>
  </div>

      <script>
// Get all the slides
const slides = document.querySelectorAll('.slide');

// Create an intersection observer
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  entries.forEach(entry => {
    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
      // Remove the active class from all the slides
      slides.forEach(slide => {
        slide.classList.remove('active');
      });

      // Add the active class to the intersecting slide
      entry.target.classList.add('active');
    }
  });
}, { threshold: 0.5 }); // The threshold value determines when the intersection is detected

// Add the observer to each slide
slides.forEach(slide => {
  observer.observe(slide);
});

// Add a resize event listener to the window object
window.addEventListener('resize', () => {
  // Find the current active slide
  const activeSlide = document.querySelector('.slide.active');

  // Scroll to the active slide
  activeSlide.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have changed the threshold from 0.5 to 1 but it dind't help for

Comment: I deleted my answer as it did not work for all slides. Did you try @BlueStreak suggestion?

Comment: yes, it is not working, maybe I did something wrong? if so, maybe you can add the new code in jsfiddle and share it for me but i tryed and it didn't work.